# Sum of $\infty$ terms in Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please help me to do this question

If $3+3a+3a^{2}+.....\infty = \frac {45}8$ , then what is the value of $a$ ?

My Approach to the Problem :-

$3(1+a+a^{2}+.....\infty) = \frac {45}8$

$1+a+a^{2}+.....\infty = \frac {45}{24}$

$a+a^{2}+.....\infty = \frac {7}{8}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: Why the downvotes ? There is absolutely no reason for it. The up- and downvotes are really weird.

Comment: Writing it with that $\infty$ in there is not done by mathematicians.  Where did this problem come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the routine well known formula for [infinite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula),

$$3+3a+3a^{2}+.....\infty = \frac {45}8$$
$$\implies \frac{3}{1-a} = \frac {45}8$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{1-a} = \frac {15}8$$
$$\implies 1-a = \frac {8}{15}$$
$$\implies \large \color{red}{a = \frac {7}{15}}$$

Comment: Hey! Just wanted to ask whether there's a formula for infinite arithmetic series

Comment: No. an infinite arithmetic series is surely divergent or oscillating (if the series is alternating) .

Comment: But with this formula , i couldn't solve for $\frac12 + \frac {1}{2\sqrt2} + \frac14+.... \infty$

Comment: @Amritanshu Did you figure out the $r$ for this case? You can take $\frac{1}{2}$ outside, and take the ratio.

Comment: You mean like this - $\frac 1{1- \frac12}$

Answer (score 1):

> Notice:
>
> $$x+xa+xa^2+\dots=xa^0+xa^1+xa^2+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}xa^n=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n=\frac{x}{1-a}$$
>
> When $|a|<1$

So, we get:

$$3+3a+3a^2+\dots=\frac{45}{8}\Longleftrightarrow\frac{3}{1-a}=\frac{45}{8}\Longleftrightarrow a=\frac{7}{15}$$

__

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: You missed the $3$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Oh sure, sorry! I fixed it :)